# Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid Edit Popup Globalization Validation Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, globalization

i have a Kendo grid that uses an edit Popup. The culture in the client is de-DE, when an user tries to edit a decimal number i.e. 8,5 Kendo sends a null to the server for that value and returns validation message "The value 8.5 is not valid for 'PropertyName'". Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    @{
       var culture =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
    }

 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Kendo/cultures/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>

  jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || kendo.parseDate(value) != null;
    },
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || kendo.parseFloat(value) != null;
    }
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    kendo.culture("@culture");
</script>

   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SalesToolkit.ViewModels.AdminEquipDimViewModel.Equipment>()
            .Name("grdEquipDim")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(dim => dim.EquipmentID).Width(50).Title("ID").Hidden(true);
                columns.Bound(dim => dim.EquipmentName).Width(140).Title("Equipment Name");
                columns.ForeignKey(dim => dim.EquipmentTypeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["EquipTypes"], "EquipmentTypeID", "EquipmentName").Width(60).Title("Type");

                columns.Bound(dim => dim.Metric).Width(55);
                columns.Bound(dim => dim.ModelVerified).Width(65);
                columns.Bound(dim => dim.LastModifiedBy).Width(130);
                columns.Bound(dim => dim.TimeStamp).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss}").Width(120);

                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
            .Scrollable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "dimGrid" })
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable()
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Field(dim => dim.EquipmentID).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(dim => dim.TimeStamp).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(dim => dim.LastModifiedBy).Editable(false);
                })
                .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(dim => dim.EquipmentID))
                .Create(update => update.Action("EquipDim_Create", "AdminEquipDim", new { mID = Model.ManufacturerID }))
                .Read(read => read.Action("EquipDim_Read", "AdminEquipDim", new { mID = Model.ManufacturerID }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("EquipDim_Update", "AdminEquipDim"))
                .Destroy(update => update.Action("EquipDim_Delete", "AdminEquipDim"))
                )
            )

 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EquipDim_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, AdminEquipDimViewModel.Equipment equipMfg)
    {            
            if (equipMfg != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                AdminEquipDim oEquipMfg = new AdminEquipDim();
                oEquipMfg.UpdateEquipDim(equipMfg);
            }

        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
```

Comment: I doubt that its sending null. It would be sending `"8,5"` (check the `Request.Form` values). If the culture on the server is not `de-DE` then the value cant be parsed to a valid number so its not bound and a `ModelState` error is added.

Comment: The culture in the server is de-DE the same in the client. I put a watch in the ViewModel property causing the issue that shows the value being null. The validation must be happening in the client even though it goes to the server.